# Реализация одного и того же интерфейса для двух разных типов в одном классе

Tags: java

Есть некий интерфейс:

```
public interface ViewableParent<C extends AfdxObject> extends Viewable{

    interface ListChangeCallback<C>{
        void doWhenChange(C object);
    }

    ListChangeCallback<C> getAddedSubListCallback();
    ListChangeCallback<C> getRemovedSubListCallback();

    default ListChangeListener<C> getChangeListener(){
        return c -> {
            while (c.next()){
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    //Проходимся по добавленным элементам
                    c.getAddedSubList().forEach(e -> {
                        //Вешаем на проперти стиля слушатель, который при изменении стиля потомка меняет стиль у родителя
                        e.styleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                                refreshStyle(c.getList(), ViewableParent.this,false));
                        //Выполяняем код add коллбэка
                        if (getAddedSubListCallback()!=null)
                            getAddedSubListCallback().doWhenChange(e);
                    });
                    //Пересчитываем стиль для родителя исходя из стилей добавляемых потомков
                    refreshStyle(c.getAddedSubList(), ViewableParent.this,true);
                } else if (c.wasRemoved() || c.wasUpdated()) {
                    //Иначе, если что-то было удалено или обновлено (здесь не уверен в корректности события update)
                    //Так же пересчитываем стиль для родителя
                    refreshStyle(c.getList(), ViewableParent.this, false);
                    //Выполняем код remove коллбэка
                    if (getRemovedSubListCallback()!=null) 
                        c.getRemoved().forEach(e -> getRemovedSubListCallback().doWhenChange(e));                    
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Параметр типа `C` обозначает тип потомка для класса, реализующего данный интерфейс. 4 из 5 классов имеют только один тип потомка, однако есть один класс, в котором потомков 2. Если в объявлении класса 2 раза написать один и тот же интерфейс с разными типами в дженерике, само собой IDE выдает ошибку. Подскажите, каким образом можно обойти данное ограничение с точки зрения архитектуры?

Comment: это не возможно. с точки зрения java в байткоде Interface<A> и Interface<B> одно и тоже. А два раза реализовать один и тот же интерфейс вам никто не разрешит

Comment: конкретно здесь проблема даже не в type erasure, а в том, что у вас будут два метода с одинаковой сигнатурой, но разными возвращаемыми типами, а так нельзя. Как вы хотите использовать класс, реализующий два интерфейса?

Comment: @zRrr, я понимаю, почему так нельзя сделать. Вопрос в пути обхода данной проблемы с точки зрения архитектурной составляющей, например в виде какого-нибудь паттерна etc. У интерфейса есть тесты, с остальными классами он отлично работает, поэтому и не хочется дублировать в классе код, переписывая default метод

Comment: можно сделать метод вроде `ViewableParent<B> asVPB()` который будет возвращать представление: объект анонимного класса, который реализует методы интерфейса `ViewableParent<B>` и вызывает методы основного класса.

Comment: @zRrr думал сначала сделать похожим образом. Однако на данный момент остановился на избавлении от интерфейса в пользу метода в утилитарном классе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не получится реализовать два раза интерфейс с разными параметризированными типами:

```
interface MyInterface<T>{
   T method();
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface<A>, MyInterface<B>{
    ...
}
```

Потому, что происходит стирание типов, и в байткоде остаются только интерфейсы с типом `Object`. Т.е. для `java` `MyInterface<A>` и `MyInterface<B>` одно и тоже.

Если бы даже, не происходило стирания, то возникли бы логические ошибки. Как ранее заметил @zRrr может возникнуть ситуация, что класс реализует два одинаковых метода, с разным возвращаемым типом.

```
public A method(){
  ...
}

public B method(){
  ...
}
```

При вызове которых, не понятно, что вызывать, и в `java` такой код не является корректным.

Если очень хочется, то можно сделать, но опять же, зависит от сигнатур методов интерфейса и не во всех случаях будет работать. Для интерфейса `Comparable` это выглядит следующим образом:

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class B implements Comparable<B> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(B o) {
        return 0;
    }
}

//E extends A or B
class Gibrid<E> implements Comparable<E> {
    final A a = new A();
    final B b = new B();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(E o) {
        if (o instanceof A)
            return a.compareTo((A) o);
        else if (o instanceof B)
            return b.compareTo((B) o);

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("object type is not correct."
                                                        +"It must be A or B");
    }
}
```

Но здесь мы уходим от проверки типов во время компиляции во время исполнения программы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако, как я уже отписал в комментарии к вопросу, я понимаю почему так сделать нельзя. Меня интересует обходной путь с точки зрения архитектуры. Какой-нибудь враппер или что-то типа того.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге пришлось отказаться от использования дженерика в описании интерфейса и немного расширить default метод. Не знаю пока, насколько это оправданно и корректно, однако все работает. Единственный момент: не ясно, что в данной ситуации было бы правильней. Вынести интерфейс коллбэка и default метод как статический в утилитарном классе или оставить так? При этом поведение метода переопределять не планируется.

```
public interface ViewableParent extends Viewable{

    interface ListChangeCallback<C>{
        void doWhenChange(C object);
    }

    default <C extends Viewable> ListChangeListener<C> getViewChangeListener(ListChangeCallback<C> addCallback, ListChangeCallback<C> removeCallback){

        return c -> {
            while (c.next()){
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    //Проходимся по добавленным элементам
                    c.getAddedSubList().forEach(e -> {
                        //Вешаем на проперти стиля слушатель, который при изменении стиля потомка меняет стиль у родителя
                        e.styleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                                refreshStyle(c.getList(),false));
                        //Выполяняем код add коллбэка
                        if (addCallback!=null)
                            addCallback.doWhenChange(e);
                    });
                    //Пересчитываем стиль для родителя исходя из стилей добавляемых потомков
                    refreshStyle(c.getAddedSubList(),true);
                } else if (c.wasRemoved() || c.wasUpdated()) {
                    //Иначе, если что-то было удалено или обновлено (здесь не уверен в корректности события update)
                    //Так же пересчитываем стиль для родителя
                    refreshStyle(c.getList(),false);
                    //Выполняем код remove коллбэка
                    if (removeCallback!=null)
                        c.getRemoved().forEach(removeCallback::doWhenChange);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```